# Intraweb TIWUserSession members losing value

Tags: delphi, intraweb

Using Delphi 2007 with bundled version of Intraweb.  Making use of the built in **usersession** mechanism.  In the usersession unit I have added public members (integer) to the TIWUserSession and these are initialized in a login screen.

I am finding sometimes the values of these public members are being lost: some calls they are proper, but other calls they are unassigned integers.  Has anyone else experienced this?

My solution at this point is to not rely on the usersession but instead use a cookie and recalculate these members based on the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Except your session is expiring or your code are modifying these public members, values on User Session members should be persistent while the session is active.